# How to change voice id in pyttsx3 (I have voice id 2)

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyttsx3

How do I change the voice id here? I tried to change it but it stays Microsoft DAVID voice.

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voices', voices [2].id)
engine.setProperty('rate', 190)
```